# What reason? "Unhandled Rejection (Error): replacement fee too low "

Tags: web3js, ether, pancakeswap

I am going to swap two BSC tokens using etherjs.
I sent approval for a transaction and then I sent a swap transaction.
I am using a Pancakeswap v2 router.

I had this error.

`Unhandled Rejection (Error): replacement fee too low (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":90,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"replacement transaction underpriced\"}}\n","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":[\"0xf8ad8201498501a13b8600830233889456562c77e4f18d05bd93a7ca32937312a138772580b844095ea7b300000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8193a071817d56681f9348220528ca9894547732326628359106082efdbc91781f956aa02b089f4ea7bb8eec4908a8f3f6ec7c879415805f8e2e0f696cee5c614f7f1f09\"],\"id\":90,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://bsc-dataseed3.defibit.io/"}, method="sendTransaction", transaction="0xf8ad8201498501a13b8600830233889456562c77e4f18d05bd93a7ca32937312a138772580b844095ea7b300000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8193a071817d56681f9348220528ca9894547732326628359106082efdbc91781f956aa02b089f4ea7bb8eec4908a8f3f6ec7c879415805f8e2e0f696cee5c614f7f1f09", code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.3.1)`

This is my code.

```
`const address = [tokenIn, tokenOut];
const to = config[config.network].addresses.recipient;

try {

  const wbnb_abi = [
    'function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)'
  ];
  
  let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(wbnb_abi);
  var data = iface.encodeFunctionData('approve', [config[config.network].addresses.router, ethers.BigNumber.from("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935")]);

  const txObj =
  {
    from: config[config.network].addresses.recipient,
    to: tokenIn,
    value: 0,
    gasLimit: 144264, // 100000
    gasPrice: 7000000000,
    data: data
  }

  try {

    account.sendTransaction(txObj).then((transaction) => {

      console.log('====================== Approve Send finished! ================= ');

      let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(pancake_route_abi);
     

      var data = iface.encodeFunctionData('swapExactTokensForTokens', [amountIn, amountOut, address, to, Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5]);


      const txObj =
      {
        from: config[config.network].addresses.recipient,
        to: config[config.network].addresses.router,
        value: 0,
        gasLimit: 144264, // 100000
        gasPrice: 7000000000, // 7000000000
        data: data
      }

      try {

        account.sendTransaction(txObj).then((transaction) => {

          console.log('====================== Swap Send finished! ================= ');
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("failed to send!!");
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("failed to send!!");
  }
```

`

Why did my transaction fail?